# Having trouble sorting the data from a file

Tags: python, file, loops

I am opening and reading a .txt file and trying to save values in the format 0.x or 0.xy or 0.xyz.

x must be a digit 1-9

y cannot be 0 or a odd number

z cannot be 0 or a even number

My current code is only saving the variables in the format 0.x but is skipping over the 0.xy and 0.xyz.

For text file has 16000 elements and contains ints, floats, and strings:

> .03243234
>
> 234.234
>
> .223
>
> 0.2
>
> MWFE
>
> etc.

```
list = []

with open("exam2data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = f.readline()
        xCounter = 0
        yCounter = 0
        zCounter = 0

        try:
            lineFloat = float(line)
            if lineFloat < 1:
                if len(line) == 4:
                    if line[3] == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        list.append(lineFloat)
                        xCounter += 1
                        
                elif len(line) == 5:
                    if line[3] == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if line[2] == 0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            y = float(line[4])
                            if (y % 2 == 0):
                                list.append(lineFloat)
                                yCounter += 1
                            else:
                                pass

                elif len(line) == 6:
                     if line[4] == 0:
                        pass
                     else:
                        if line[5] == 0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            if line[3] == 0:
                                pass
                            else:
                                y = float(line[4])
                                z = float(line[5])
                                if (y % 2 == 0):
                                    if (z % 2 == 1):
                                        list.append(lineFloat)
                                        zCounter += 1
                                    else:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    pass


        except:
            pass

print(len(list))
print(', '.join(map(str, list)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad guys. Forgot to strip \n after reading the line. I added the strip method and adjusted my strings for that.

```
line = data.rstrip("\n")
```

The resulting code:

```
list = []

with open("exam2data.txt") as f:
    for data in f:
        data = f.readline()
        xCounter = 0
        yCounter = 0
        zCounter = 0
        line = data.rstrip("\n")
        try:
            lineFloat = float(line)
            if lineFloat < 1:
                if len(line) == 3:
                    if line[2] == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        list.append(lineFloat)
                        xCounter += 1

                elif len(line) == 4:
                    if line[3] == 0:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if line[2] == 0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            y = float(line[3])
                            if (y % 2 == 0):
                                list.append(lineFloat)
                                yCounter += 1
                            else:
                                pass

                elif len(line) == 5:
                     if line[4] == 0:
                        pass
                     else:
                        if line[3] == 0:
                            pass
                        else:
                            if line[2] == 0:
                                pass
                            else:
                                y = float(line[3])
                                z = float(line[4])
                                if (y % 2 == 0):
                                    if (z % 2 == 1):
                                        list.append(lineFloat)
                                        zCounter += 1
                                    else:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    pass


        except:
            pass

print(len(list))
print(', '.join(map(str, list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has to be better asked.  What happens when the number has no "z" for example.  x must be a digit but you have strings in the file?    Some example input and expected output would help.  If I understand the question, the following should work.  I prefer to use math to isolate the digits but that is personal preference.  And note that I added a test for numbers equal to or less than zero.  You can never trust the contents of a file IMHO.

```
def test_xyz(num_in):
    x, remain_x=divmod(num_in*10, 1)
    print "test_xyz", num_in, 
    if (1 <= x <= 9):
        print "good x", x
    else:
        print "Bad x" , x
        return

    if remain_x > 0:
        y, remain_y=divmod(remain_x*10, 1)
        if (y != 0) and (y%2 == 0):
            print "good y"
        else:
            print "Bad y", y
            return

        if remain_y > 0:
            z, remain_z=divmod(remain_y*10, 1)
            if (z != 0) and (z%2 != 0):
                print "good z"
            else:
                print "Bad z", z
    return

##-----------------------------------------------------------
test_data=""".223
0.2
1.234
0.23456
0.023
0.101"""

recs=test_data.split("\n")
for rec in recs:
    rec=float(rec)
    print "\n number", rec
    if rec < 1 and rec > 0:
        test_xyz(rec)
    else:
        print "number >= 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a text-matching approach. I broke each search pattern out into its own function, and introduced a decorator to track the results.

Each matching function returns a string on success or None on failure. The functions are mutually exclusive (at most one can succeed) so I can safely merge the results with `or` (`None or "text"` gives `"text"`).

```
INFILE = "exam2data.txt"
XS = set("123456789")
YS = set("2468")
ZS = set("13579")

def count_not_none(fn):
    """
    A decorator which counts the number of times the wrapped
      function returns a value other than None
    """
    def wrapped_fn(s):
        result = fn(s)
        if result is not None:
            wrapped_fn.count += 1
        return result
    wrapped_fn.count = 0
    return wrapped_fn

@count_not_none
def match_x(line):
    if len(line) == 3 and line[:2] == "0." and line[2] in XS:
        return line
    else:
        return None

@count_not_none
def match_xy(line):
    if len(line) == 4 and line[:2] == "0." and line[2] in XS and line[3] in YS:
        return line
    else:
        return None

@count_not_none
def match_xyz(line):
    if len(line) == 5 and line[:2] == "0." and line[2] in XS and line[3] in YS and line[4] in ZS:
        return line
    else:
        return None

def main():
    # search for matching lines
    matches = []
    with open(INFILE) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            line = line.strip()
            result = match_x(line) or match_xy(line) or match_xyz(line)
            if result is not None:
                matches.append(line)
    # report on the results
    print("Matched 0.x   {} times".format(match_x.count))
    print("Matched 0.xy  {} times".format(match_xy.count))
    print("Matched 0.xyz {} times".format(match_xyz.count))
    print("{} matches found".format(len(matches)))
    print(", ".join(matches))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```